# Accessing a view variable in another view -Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a view called View1.ctp .In this view am calling a controller function called 'Captcha',where its view is captcha.ctp .I have a variable called $text in view captcha.ctp.I want to access this $text variable in my view1.ctp.How should i do ?
(Note :Cakephp version -2.3)
         `View1.ctp`

```
       <h1>Add Comment</h1>
      <?php
       $post_id= $posts['Post']['id'];
       echo $this->Form->create('Comment',array('action' => 'comment','url' =>          array($post_id,$flag)));
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('text', array('rows' => '3'));
        echo "Enter Captcha Code:    ";  
        echo $this->Html->image(
       array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'captcha'));
       echo $this->Form->input('code');
       echo $this->Form->end('Add comment'); 
          ?>

         captcha.ctp:

          <?php 
           $this->Session->read(); 
           $text = rand(10000,99996); 
           $_SESSION["vercode"] = $text; 
           $height = 25; 
           $width = 65; 
           $image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
           $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
           $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
           $font_size = 14; 
           imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 
           imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80); 
           ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to turn the Captcha view into a [Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) instead, which is more suitable. So move the captcha.ctp to app/View/Helper/CaptchaHelper.php, and wrap it's contents in a class, like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class CaptchaHelper extends AppHelper {

    function create() {
        // This line doesn't make much sense as no data from the session is used
        // $this->Session->read(); 

        $text = rand(10000, 99996); 

        // Don't use the $_SESSION superglobal in Cake apps
        // $_SESSION["vercode"] = $text; 

        // Use SessionComponent::write instead
        $session = new SessionComponent(new ComponentCollection());
        $session->write('vercode', $text);

        $height = 25; 
        $width = 65; 
        $image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
        $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
        $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
        $font_size = 14; 
        imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white);

        // Return the generated image
        return imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80);
    }

}
```

Then in your PostsController, add `Captcha` to the helpers array:

```
public $helpers = array('Captcha');
```

(Or if you already have a helpers array, just append it to that array.)

Then from your View1.ctp you can just call the helper to return the image:

```
echo $this->Html->image($this->Captcha->create());
```

It's "expected" value will be stored in the Session key `vercode`, which you can also read from your PostsController in your form handling logic.

Comment: but sir i need to access this vercode in another controller CommentsController.php not in PostsController.ctp

Comment: I am getting this error sir.Error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object

Comment: @user1479469 That error would be from the `$this->Session->read()`, which makes no sense in the Helper function, so I would drop that line altogether. To read the Session key from another controller just use `SessionComponent::read('vercode')` from that controller.

Comment: oki sir ..i changed ..and i get this Error - Non-static method SessionComponent::write() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context [APP\View\Helper\CaptchaHelper.php, line 47]

Comment: OK, in that case add the SessionComponent to the `$components` array of your controller: `public $components = array('Session');` and then use `$this->Session->read('vercode');` instead.

Comment: no sir ..i am getting error with this line $this->Session->write('vercode',$text); in CaptchaHelper.php .if i use  SessionComponent::write('vercode', $text); my error is Non-static method SessionComponent::write() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context .if i use $this->Session->write('vercode',$text); my error is Call to a member function write() on a non-object

Comment: Oh, like that. In that case, initiate the SessionComponent manually from the Helper, I updated the answer to show how. Doesn't throw any errors in my Cake 2.3 app like this.

Comment: oh no sir :(am not getting it rite .Am getting my captcha image to be displayed as 2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�

Comment: sir i think because i dint change my content type to image/png .Where should i change it .earlier i had it in my controller action captcha $this->layout=false;
 $this->response->type('png');